# MVC Code First - cascade delete 1 to 1 relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a `User` and `Profile` Entity which they have 1-1 relation.

**User Entity and configurations**

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class UserConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfig()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.Profile).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.User);
    }
}
```

**Profile Entity and configs**

```
public class Profile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Profile>
{
    public ProfileConfig()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.User).WithRequiredDependent(x => x.Profile).Map(x => x.MapKey("UserID")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

However when I try to delete a list of users I get this exception below :

```
List<User> users = _user.Where(x => m.SelectedUsersID.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
users.ForEach(x => _user.Remove(x));
```

`A relationship from the 'Profile_User' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'Profile_User_Source' must also in the 'Deleted' state.`

I've got no idea what is wrong, please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I could resolve this by deleting both entities. that means I had to delete `Profile` and `User` both

```
users.ForEach(x => _profile.Remove(x.Profile));
users.ForEach(x => _user.Remove(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting a User but the User isn't configured to cascade deletes. This means the Profile will not be deleted and violates the database's integrity. EF is prevents the database and therefore raises the error.

You should configure to cascade deletes as well.

Comment: I tried out this too: `HasRequired(x => x.Profile).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.User).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);` but I still got same error. 
Anyway I found the answer and wrote above, Big thanks